# How Can I copy highlighted lines in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I used Compare Plugin in Notepad++. I want copy only highlighted lines. The lines are not bookmarked.

http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/4524/highlightlines.png

Comment: Flagged as off topic.  Please see the FAQ.

Comment: I read the FAQ..Why is offtopic Ben?

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming or software development within the scope defined in the FAQ @ [link](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Consider editing the question or leaving comments for improvement if you believe the question can be reworded to fit within the scope. Read more about closed questions @ [link](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close).

Comment: The question is not off topic Ben! off topic is talking about girls..

Answer (score 3):

The only way I have found to do this so far, and it's not ideal if there are loads of lines that are different, is this.

1. Put your cursor at the top of the file.
2. You can then click the "Next" (the down arrow) icon and this will take you to the first difference.
3. Press ctrl+F2 to toggle the bookmark
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until you're at the end of the file
5. Open the Search Menu > Bookmark > Copy Bookmarked Lines.

You can then paste the lines wherever you want. I'm not sure if maybe you could write this into a macro.

Comment: You can't put this in a macro (NPP v 6.6.7), because the Next button will jump to the first line of several consecutive ones marked by the comparison. You have to manually put the cursor on each of those consecutive lines and then mark it. Thanks for the ctrl+F2 tip, btw.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to do it automatically, but you can enable multi-editing (settings->prefs->editing).
Then, you can CTRL + Select the lines you want, copy and paste.

Comment: i want copy only highlighted text not the selected text

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the same thing I had about 1000 lines that were missing, and I needed to select them and get them to a different file. They were grouped in about 50 or so blocks.

I went and selected the added (green lines), then pressed tab to indent those lines. I did this for each of the blocks. It went pretty quick since one hand was on the mouse and click scroll to select, the other was on the tab key.

I then re-sorted the file, which put the indents at the top. Re-did the compare to make sure I didn't miss anything.

Now all the new lines are at the top. I just select and copy-paste to the new file, then shift-tab to un-indent.